# Find rows based on ordering of previous row

Tags: sql, postgresql

There is a table purchase **(id,title, purchase-date, quantity)** 
Find purchases such that the previous purchase was of larger quantity

**My Thoughts :** 
It feels like if I was able to do a loop kind of thing and for a 
**(id,purchase-date)** I could  find the row earlier than that then 
it will be doable
.
But what if the previous entry or multiple entries  in the purchase table
has the same purchase-date? when executed a query like - 
**select  * from purchase order by purchase-date** 
Is the order well-defined in case purchase-date are same for two rows ? 
Or it could appear in any order ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `lag()`:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             lag(quantity) over (order by purchase_date) as prev_quantity
      from purchases p
     ) p
where prev_quantity > quantity;
```

Note:  This is for all purchases.  Often such a question would be asked about a customer -- but there doesn't appear to be one in the table.  If there were, you would use a `partition by`:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             lag(quantity) over (partition by customer_id order by purchase_date) as prev_quantity
      from purchases p
     ) p
where prev_quantity > quantity;
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any alternative to lag function. Like if we wanted to access the row after the current row ?

Comment: @MonuDidi . . . You would use `lead()`.